# git mv command returns with fatal error

Tags: git, repository, mv

The layout of the repo looks like this

```
directory -> CEG4110-Repo
                 .git
directory ->     subdir_hello_world
                   myfile-a.java
                   myfile-b.java
```

I am using the following command:

```
git mv myfile-a.java C:/Users/Kelley/git/CEG4110-Repo
```

trying to make the directory layout look like this:

```
directory ->  CEG4110-Repo
                  myfile-a.java
                  .git
directory->       subdir_hello_world
                  myfile-b.java`
```

but the error I'm getting is this:

```
fatal: C:/Users/Kelley/git/CEG4110-Repo:
'C:/Users/Kelley/git/CEG4110-Repo' is outside repository
```

I've tried googling the error message and I understand that it thinks that the CEG4110-Repo directory is outside of the repository but that doesn't make much sense. Is there any way for me to make this directory part of the repo without messing up hours of work? Any help would be appreciated.

> I didn't think after all the cloning and stuff I've done moving a file up one directory was going to be the brick wall in my progress...

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a relative path to specify the destination of your file?

```
cd subdir_hello_world
git mv myfile-a.java ../
```

I tested this and it appears to be working.

**Update:**

It appears that the file you want to move is currently untracked.  In this case, you should not be using `git mv` to move the file because it isn't even part of your repository yet.  Instead, just use plain `mv`:

```
cd subdir_hello_world
mv myfile-a.java ../
```

After this, you can `git add` this file in the desired location and carry on with your work.

Comment: fatal: ../: '../' is outside repository
either way it says im over stepping the repository

Comment: This works for me.  There must be some other problem with your setup, or the directory structure you gave us is not accurate.

Comment: structure: 
CEG4110-Repo [ .git subdir_hello_world [ myfile-a.java myfile-b.java ] ] 

The repository has been working flawlessly and initial setup happened in the CEG4110-Repo directory

Comment: Question: Type `git status` from the `CEG4110-Repo` folder.  Do you get any output?

Comment: `C:\Users\Kelley\git\CEG4110-Repo>git status-------------------------
On branch master-------------------------
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.---------------
Untracked files:------------------------
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)-----------------

        subdir_hello_world/Hello4110-a.java----------------
        subdir_hello_world/Hello4110-b.java----------------

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)`---------------

Comment: @newToRacket Don't use `git mv` on untracked files.  Instead, just move them around as you would normal files outside of Git.

Comment: the professor had us use the standard move cmd as you suggest to show why its worse than git mv. so he had us do the move, then move them back. is there any way i can re track them? ( so he wanted us to move them, move them back, then git mv them to show correct vs. difficult)

Comment: You need to `git add` the files.  But I believe I have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move files inside the same repo, why would you provide a path like `C:/...`?
Open git bash inside your repo folder and then you can do like so:
`git mv ./folder ./` --> move to root`

In my case `./` did the job. Without that it was throwing the mentioned error `is outside repository`